# Select all pages except the 3 last ones

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to select all pages of a document except the 3 last ones. My final goal is to apply a style to text who have a specific font name and a specific font size. I am receiving an error message when running the code below about my 3rd code line : "object doesn't support this property or method". Any idea what this is about? Thanks!

```
Sub aHeadlines()

Dim V As Integer
Dim Z As Integer
V = ActiveDocument.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
Z = 3
Dim rgePages As Range
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=1
Set rgePages = Selection.Range
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=V - Z
rgePages.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
rgePages.Select


With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Bold = True
    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    End With
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way simpler:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  With .Range(0, .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, _
    Count:=.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) - 2).End - 1).Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Information` is a property of the `Range` object, not `Document`.

```
V = ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
```

NOTE:
It is rarely necessary to select anything when working with VBA. Using the `Selection` object slows down your code as the cursor moves with each change of the selection which means the screen has to be redrawn each time. Instead of `Selection` use the appropriate object for what you are trying to do, e.g. `Range`, `Table`, `Shape`, etc.

Your code can be rewritten using Range as below:

```
Sub aHeadlines()

   Dim V As Integer
   Dim Z As Integer
   V = ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
   Z = 3
   Dim rgePages As Range

   Set rgePages = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=V - Z)
   rgePages.End = rgePages.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
   rgePages.Start = ActiveDocument.Range.Start

   With rgePages.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Font.Size = 10
      .Font.Name = "Arial"
      .Font.Bold = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      With .Replacement
         .ClearFormatting
         .Text = ""
         .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
      End With
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```